# Unable to convert array of arrays to array of objects without index in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, response

I have the following JSON response which I get from an API

```
[
  [
   {"companyID":"U72200TG2005PTC045191","companyName":"OPEN TEXT TECHNOLOGIES INDIA PRIVATE LIMITED"},
   {"companyID":"U51909HR2002PTC034956","companyName":"OPEN WAYS MARKETING PRIVATE LIMITED"},
   {"companyID":"U00892HR2005PTC035863","companyName":"OPEN HOUSE DIGITAL MEDIA PRIVATE LIMITED"},
   {"companyID":"U00804KA1999PTC024813","companyName":"OPEN LEAF STOCKS AND SHARES PRIVATE LIMITED"},
   {"companyID":"U72300KA2000PTC026648","companyName":"OPEN STREAM TECHNOLOGIES (INDIA) PRIVATE LIMITED"},
   {"companyID":"U72200KA2003PTC032219","companyName":"OPENCLOVIS SOLUTIONS PRIVATE LIMITED"},
   {"companyID":"U72200KA2003PTC032083","companyName":"OPEN-SILICON RESEARCH PRIVATE LIMITED"},
   {"companyID":"U72900KA2003PTC033042","companyName":"OPENGEAR NETWORKS PRIVATE LIMITED"},
   {"companyID":"U72200DL2005PTC170412","companyName":"OPEN SOLUTIONS SOFTWARE SERVICES PRIVATE LIMITED"},
   {"companyID":"U72112MP1985PTC002837","companyName":"OPEN END SPINNERS PVT LTD"}
  ]
]
```

I want to convert it into a proper array of objects

```
[
{"companyID":"U72200TG2005PTC045191","companyName":"OPEN TEXT TECHNOLOGIES INDIA PRIVATE LIMITED"},
{"companyID":"U51909HR2002PTC034956","companyName":"OPEN WAYS MARKETING PRIVATE LIMITED"},
{"companyID":"U00892HR2005PTC035863","companyName":"OPEN HOUSE DIGITAL MEDIA PRIVATE LIMITED"}
]
```

But I am unable to achieve this

This is the codes which I have tried

```
$data = json_decode($result,true);

$new_array = array();
foreach ($data[0] as $to_obj)
{
  new_array[] = (object)$to_obj;
}

return ($new_array);
```

$result is the JSON which is coming from the API. When I did this the $new_array returned

```
array:10 [
  0 => {#546
    +"companyID": "U72200TG2005PTC045191"
    +"companyName": "OPEN TEXT TECHNOLOGIES INDIA PRIVATE LIMITED"
  }
  1 => {#576
    +"companyID": "U51909HR2002PTC034956"
    +"companyName": "OPEN WAYS MARKETING PRIVATE LIMITED"
  }
  2 => {#574
    +"companyID": "U00892HR2005PTC035863"
    +"companyName": "OPEN HOUSE DIGITAL MEDIA PRIVATE LIMITED"
  }
  3 => {#552
    +"companyID": "U00804KA1999PTC024813"
    +"companyName": "OPEN LEAF STOCKS AND SHARES PRIVATE LIMITED"
  }
  4 => {#548
    +"companyID": "U72300KA2000PTC026648"
    +"companyName": "OPEN STREAM TECHNOLOGIES (INDIA) PRIVATE LIMITED"
  }
  5 => {#572
    +"companyID": "U72200KA2003PTC032219"
    +"companyName": "OPENCLOVIS SOLUTIONS PRIVATE LIMITED"
  }
  6 => {#571
    +"companyID": "U72200KA2003PTC032083"
    +"companyName": "OPEN-SILICON RESEARCH PRIVATE LIMITED"
  }
  7 => {#570
    +"companyID": "U72900KA2003PTC033042"
    +"companyName": "OPENGEAR NETWORKS PRIVATE LIMITED"
  }
  8 => {#569
    +"companyID": "U72200DL2005PTC170412"
    +"companyName": "OPEN SOLUTIONS SOFTWARE SERVICES PRIVATE LIMITED"
  }
  9 => {#560
    +"companyID": "U72112MP1985PTC002837"
    +"companyName": "OPEN END SPINNERS PVT LTD"
  }
]
```

But the array index is also coming. I want it to be like the following

```
[
    {"companyID":"U72200TG2005PTC045191","companyName":"OPEN TEXT TECHNOLOGIES INDIA PRIVATE LIMITED"},
    {"companyID":"U51909HR2002PTC034956","companyName":"OPEN WAYS MARKETING PRIVATE LIMITED"},
    {"companyID":"U00892HR2005PTC035863","companyName":"OPEN HOUSE DIGITAL MEDIA PRIVATE LIMITED"}
    ]
```

How do I achieve this? I have tried but my final JSON response has indexes of the array which I dont want.

Comment: i believe this is not a issue this is behaviour of php array, if an array do not have any index then by default it will take numeric index, have a look at https://3v4l.org/FkPPS

Comment: @Ajeesh I think `$data = json_decode($result,true);` and using `$data[0]` will give you expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would bypass the iteration this way:

```
$data = (array)json_decode($result);
return reset($data);
```

That will preserve your inner values as objects and still return the inner values as objects.

If you must iterate, then you should call `array_values` as the return:

```
// Everything that you have above, just replace the return with
return array_values($new_array);
```

This will eliminate the keys and it will make it so that `json_encode` will treat it as an array, not a specialized object.

That said, if you're doing a `var_dump` or a `var_export`, it will always include the index numbers. That's just part of the formatting.